# How to mirror object relative to global plane

Tags: opengl

I am rendering several hierarchically ordered objects, most of which are only aware of the relative coordinate system of their parent:

```
room()
{
    glPushMatrix();
    glMultMatrix(...);

    glBegin();
    ...
    glEnd();

    box();
    glPopMatrix();
}

box()
{
    glPushMatrix();
    glMultMatrix(...);

    glBegin();
    ...
    glEnd();

    line();
    glPopMatrix();
}

line()
{
    glPushMatrix();
    glMultMatrix(...);

    lineEntitiy();
    //mirror with respect to a global plane
    lineEntity();

    glPopMatrix();
}

lineEntity()
{
    glBegin();
    ...
    glEnd();
}
```

I now want to mirror one of these objects (`line` and `lineEntity` in this example) at a known global plane; how would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally by stopping to use OpenGL's matrix stack. No serious program used that, most roll their own matrix math and only load the final result with glLoadMatrix, or, in a modern OpenGL program load it into a matrix uniform. Contrary to popular belief, the OpenGL matrix functions are not never were and never will be GPU accelerated.

By not being tied into the matrix stack of fixed function OpenGL, you can tap into any step of the transformation hierachy and insert other transformations, like a mirror transformation.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of those things that would probably be easier if you weren't using the old/deprecated GL matrix functions as you can be in more control of exactly what spaces matrices are transforming between.

However the principle is the same:

Pre-multiply the current model transformation matrix by a matrix which reflects about the plane in question. Your plane needs to be in the appropriate space, so if (as is traditional in the old GL scheme) you have both view and model matrices concatenated, you will need to take the camera transform into account.

So what you have is something like:

```
Matrix = View * Model
```

And you need:

```
Matrix' = View * Reflect * Model
```

So you either need to seperate those transforms out, or else do something like:

```
Matrix' = (View * Reflect * InverseView) * (View * Model)
```

The latter part of this is the current ModelView matrix, and the former part is a constant for your current view. The `InverseView * View` part in the middle will cancel, resulting in the correct transform. However this does involve some effectively redundant maths, including a matrix inversion, and hopefully demonstrates why it would be better to perform your own matrix operations and directly produce the transform you need.